# Accessing JS function variables through function instance

Tags: javascript, function, variables, closures, this

I was just trying to understand the behavior of the variables defined in function in different ways. So I just tried out some code and concluded below as put in comments. Please tell if I understand anything wrong. Or just add if I miss anything.

I want to know how can I access variables declared on function like `functionName.variableName` through function instances (`objTempFun1` and `objTempFun2`) like I can define methods inside function to expose closure variables through function instances.

```
function tempFun() {
    this.val1 = "this.var1";
    var val2 = "var var2"; //locally scoped var, not added to function instance nor to the prototype

    this.getLocalVar = function () {
        return val2;
    };

    this.setLocalVar = function (arg) {
        val2 = arg;
    };
}

tempFun.prototype.val3 = "fun.proto.var3";
tempFun.val4 = "fun.var4";

var objTempFun1 = new tempFun();
var objTempFun2 = new tempFun();

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Variables defined as `this.variableName`
        1. Are declared on prototype
        2. Have separate values across instances
        3. Cannot be accessed on function itself
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
document.write("<br />obj1-this.var1:   " + objTempFun1.val1 + "<br />");
document.write("obj2-this.var1:   " + objTempFun2.val1 + "<br />");
document.write("fun-this.var1:   " + tempFun.val1 + "<br />");

objTempFun1.val1 = "this.var1x";
objTempFun2.val1 = "this.var1y";
document.write("obj1-this.var1:   " + objTempFun1.val1 + "<br />");
document.write("obj2-this.var1:   " + objTempFun2.val1 + "<br />");

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Variables defined inside function as `var variableName`
        1. Are closure-scoped; defined neither on function nor on prototype
        2. Have separate values across function instances
        3. Can only be accessed through function instance by adding methods on 
           a prototype (as above getLocalVar and setLocalVar methods)
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
document.write("obj1-var var2:   " + objTempFun1.val2 + "<br />");
document.write("obj2-var var2:   " + objTempFun2.val2 + "<br />");
document.write("fun-var var2:   " + tempFun.val2 + "<br />");
document.write("obj1-printLocalVar:   " + objTempFun1.getLocalVar() + "<br />");
document.write("obj2-printLocalVar:   " + objTempFun2.getLocalVar() + "<br />");
objTempFun1.setLocalVar("var var2x");
objTempFun2.setLocalVar("var var2y");
document.write("obj1-printLocalVar:   " + objTempFun1.getLocalVar() + "<br />");
document.write("obj2-printLocalVar:   " + objTempFun2.getLocalVar() + "<br />");

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Variables defined as `functionName.prototype.variablename`
        1. Are declared on prototype
        2. Have separate values across function instances
        3. Cannot be accessed on function itself
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
document.write("obj1-this.proto.var3:   " + objTempFun1.val3 + "<br />");
document.write("obj2-this.proto.var3:   " + objTempFun2.val3 + "<br />");
document.write("fun-this.proto.var3:   " + tempFun.val3 + "<br />");
objTempFun1.val3 = "fun.proto.var3x";
objTempFun2.val3 = "fun.proto.var3y";
document.write("obj1-this.proto.var3:   " + objTempFun1.val3 + "<br />");
document.write("obj2-this.proto.var3:   " + objTempFun2.val3 + "<br />");

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Variables defined as `functionName.variablename`
        1. Become member of function (or say 'F'unction instance, which is tempFun) 
           not the function instances (which are objTempFun1 & objTempFun2 above)
        2. Cannot be accessed on function instances
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
document.write("obj1-fun.var4:   " + objTempFun1.val4 + "<br />");
document.write("obj2-fun.var4:   " + objTempFun2.val4 + "<br />");
document.write("fun-fun.var4:   " + tempFun.val4 + "<br />");
```

Find JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/Kzp5m/1/embedded/js,result).

Comment: _"Variables defined as `this.variableName` 1. Are declared on prototype"_ - No, they're declared on the instance, but are accessible from prototype methods. If they were declared on the prototype then they would not _"2. Have separate values across instances."_

Comment: The first and arguably the most important rules are that (a) vars like `val2` declared inside a function are 'private' and only accessible for reading/writing externally via privileged methods of the function, and (b) for a method to be privileged, it must be a function defined inside the outer function, and either returned, attached as an event handler, or defined in the form `this.foo = function(){...}` (in which cae the outer function must invoked as a constructor with keyword "new"). Externally defined methods are always 'public' but not 'privileged'.

Comment: @nnnnnn "but are accessible from prototype methods", for example? And vars I declared on protorype `val3` have separate values across `objTempFun1` and `objTempFun2`

Answer (score 0):

The [`constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) provides access to the function which constructed an object.